# How to use "useEffect" and "useCallback"?

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, next.js13, react-usecallback

I am making a Nextjs. application and in my app i have a header which contains an image and that image is fetched from a DB..

```
useEffect(() => {
     const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'))
     data.profilePic === null
        ? setDp('')
        : setDp(`https://checkkapi.newsarenaindia.in/${data.profilePic}`)
     setUserData(data)
  }, [])
```

this is my useEffect i am fetching user profilePic from localStorage.
 and i am using nextjs page routing and when i routing in my application this header component re renders every time and reloads the image which is i think is not a best user experience..

i tried using `React.memo(header)` but that didnt work..
is there any solution to this...

Comment: React.memo only memoizes the rendered output. One way to avoid the re-render is to use a Layout component that wraps around your page components. The layout component will contain the Header, and by doing this, you can ensure the Header is not unmounted and remounted.This way, your Header component will remain mounted as you navigate between pages, provided that your pages use the same Layout.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you apply layout.tsx for those pages where you need to keep the header with the user avatar. Then you will not lose state.
Reference:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts

Also you can try any of the state managers to save global state instead of component state.
For example, you can use Redux Toolkit for this. Reference:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/